# UIDatePicker not updating the label in view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uilabel, uidatepicker

I am trying to show the date on a label which I have drwan in storyboard for that view however each time I try to change the date, it is showing today's date only...Plz help
In My .h file

```
IBOutlet UILabel *datelabel;
UIActionSheet *pickerViewPopup;
UIDatePicker *pickerView;
-(IBAction)dateButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

`

In my .m file

```
-(IBAction)dateButtonClicked:(id)sender {

[self showPickerView];
```

}

```
-(void)showPickerView {

pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self    cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

pickerView = nil;
pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];
((UIDatePicker*)pickerView).datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;


UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self  action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];  

[pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];
[pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerView];
[pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];
[pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 464)];
}
-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {

NSDate *myDate = pickerView.date;    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMM d, hh:mm aa"];
NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];
self.datelabel.text=prettyVersion;
[pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}

-(void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender{
[pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @pratik bhiyani... Have you changed anything in the code?

Comment: Code edited to remove extra characters (****) which were causing confusion

Comment: what is nslog of prettyVersion..

Comment: and what about your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

You have taken `datelabel` as an instance variable and not as @property. You can't access it with `self.datelabel`. So in your `doneButtonPressed:`...

Change following line

```
self.datelabel.text=prettyVersion;
```

with

```
datelabel.text=prettyVersion;
```

BTW... XCode must be showing a warning on this line, not?

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *datelabel;

Comment: I see... if you print myDate on console, does it print today's date? Want to trace the actual problem. Is label not getting refreshed or pickerView.date is not returning selected date!!

Comment: Yes, once it updates the label with todays' date(Not with any other date)...but when I try to update by hitting the same button and try to change to any other date then it does not change....That means it is not taking any other date other than todays that too from the first time only...

Comment: So... without changing anything in your code, i run it. And it works perfect. Updates label with the selection in date picker!!

Comment: Have you added UILabel in view and sent reference outlet to UILabel *datelabel and the tried the code with success?

Comment: Are ou trying this in a device or simulater cause I am doing it in a simulater may be thats why facing this issue? what say? I tried with NSLog as well it shows todays date only ...no change

Comment: yes exactly your code...Added UILabel as subView. Run on iOS6 simulator and then in iOS5 simulator. Code works perfect!!

Comment: Thanx atif...I am really grateful...I just deleted some code which I didnt include in the question and saw the thing working now.....Thanx for boosting my morale.....

Comment: On the top left of each answer, there are up and down buttons. Press up button for up-vote. Below you can see a tick (check) mark, if you click it, it becomes selected with green fill color. This is used to accept an answer